# transit in Dammam airport

Tags: visas, transit, tickets, check-in, saudi-arabia

I have a ticket from Istanbul to Jakarta, but I have to change planes in Dammam. Can I enter the transit visa area with just my online check-in boarding pass? I don't have any luggage, either.

Comment: For all visa questions we need to know the nationality of the person traveling. And often also whether they have visa for other countries.

Comment: ... Another kiwi.com thing looks like. We will need the nationality of the traveler as mentioned by @Willeke